# How to recover meta data in the email of new order sent to the WooCommerce admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I have add a custom field for each product variation of my store :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options_pricing', 'bbloomer_add_rangement_to_variations', 10, 3 );

function bbloomer_add_rangement_to_variations( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
            'id' => 'rangement[' . $loop . ']',
            'placeholder' => 'Ex : Armoire 2',
            'label' => __('Rangement', 'woocommerce'),
            'desc_tip' => 'true',
            'class' => 'short',
            'wrapper_class' => 'form-row',
            'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'rangement', true )
)
);
}
```

And I have stored this into variation metadata

```
// 3. Store custom field value into variation data

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'bbloomer_add_rangement_variation_data' );

function bbloomer_add_rangement_variation_data( $variations ) {
$variations['rangement'] = '<div class="woocommerce_rangement">Custom Field: <span>' . get_post_meta( $variations[ 'variation_id' ], 'rangement', true ) . '</span></div>';
return $variations;
}
```

And now, I would like to display this metadata in the mail sent to the administrator when he has a new order, but I don't want to display it on the payment page or in the customer's mail.

Could you help me to solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to display my custom field in cart and email with this code :

```
// display custom field in cart and email  
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'showing_rgt_in_cart_items', 99, 3 );
function showing_rgt_in_cart_items( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    // The WC_Product object
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    // Get the  rangement
    $rgt = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'rangement', true );
    // When rgt doesn't exist
    if(empty($rgt)) return $item_name;

    // Add the rangement field
    $item_name .= '<br><small class="product-sku">' . __( "Rangement: ", "woocommerce") . $rgt . '</small>';

    return $item_name;
}
```

But how could I only display it in admin email ?